# LiveData, DiffUtil and object references

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata, android-diffutils

There is `LiveData` which is a list of users:

```
val users: MutableLiveData<List<User>>
```

Then it is updated:

```
val usersValues = users.getValues()
val user = usersValues[0]
user.name = "new-name"
users.post(usersValues)
```

And `DiffUtil` doesn't see different because `User` is the same object, so it's just updated inside `Adapter`.

```
fun areContentsTheSame(int a, int b): Boolean {
    val oldUser //User@666
    val newUser //User@666
    return oldUser.id == newUser.id || oldUser.name == newUser.name
}
```

One solution is to create a new instance or a copy, then `DiffUtil` will notice difference. Is there anything better?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

```
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean
        = oldList[oldItemPosition].id == newList[newItemPosition].id
```

You can modify a bit according to your requirements
if you want to check by ids or something else